# UITableView and parse - laggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, parse-platform

I'm using a PFQueryTableViewController with Parse in my IOS 8 Objective-c iPhone app.

My list consists of a label and a UIImageView where both the label text and image are downloaded from a row in my Parse core. I'm using this code to achieve this:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Story"];

    return query;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [[self objects] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Download the header image from parse
PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"Image"];
[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        // Set the cellImage to the cell if it's not nil
        if (cellImage == nil) {
            // nil - do nothing
            NSLog(@"nil");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"not nil");
            // Set the image
            UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:40];
            cellImageView.image = cellImage;
        }
    }
}];

// Configure the cell
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:10];
nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Title"];
nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// Make the cell transparent
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new];

// Resize the cell
[cell sizeToFit];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Hide the tabBar and show the readButton
[self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];

// Segue over to the viewing page
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];

// Get the tapped cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *title = ((UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:10]).text;

// Set selectedStory
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
sharedManager.selectedStory = title;

// Set openedStory to YES as we opened a story
openedStory = YES;
}
```

This code works good, but the scrolling is a bit laggy, which I think is because it's downloading the image whenever the cell is shown. I thought of created a simple solution by creating an array of images locally and have them only download once, but it has to load 1 time minimum when the app launches. I need to somehow run the download method asynchronously (or another solution that would work).

**How can I achieve this?**

(I'm using storyboards)

**EDIT**

[image]

Thanks in advance!
Erik

**EDIT 2:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (![self.shownIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {

    [self.shownIndexes addObject:indexPath];
    UIView *weeeeCell = [cell contentView];

    weeeeCell.layer.transform = self.initialTransform;
    weeeeCell.layer.opacity = 0.8;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:0 animations:^{
        weeeeCell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        weeeeCell.layer.opacity = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
}
```

**and**

```
                if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hypothesis about the problem is right, and your idea about a solution is right, too.  The additional requirement that you mention about preloading the images is a little fuzzy.

Must they be loaded before the table appears?  If they are loaded asynchronously, which they should be, then you'll need to block user's access to the table until the requests are complete.  You're replace the poor experience of not seeing the images right away with the worse experience of not seeing the table at all.

I think the better answer is to just load lazily. The outline of the solution is:

Declare a dictionary of images (to be indexed by the indexPaths) and be sure to initialize it to an empty dictionary...

```
@interface MyViewController ()  // replace 'MyViewController' with your class
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *images;
@end
```

Use that collection in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UIImageView *cellImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:40];
    UIImage *cachedImage = self.images[indexPath];
    if (cachedImage) {
        cellImageView.image = cachedImage;
    } else {
        cellImageView.image = // put a place holder image here

        // load lazily, but read on.  the code in the callback should assume
        // nothing about the state of the table when it runs

        PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"Image"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            // what if this gets run a second time before the first request finishes?
            // no worries, check for that here:
            if (!error && !self.images[indexPath]) {
                UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                self.images[indexPath] = cellImage;
                // this is important:  don't refer to cell in here, it may be
                // scrolled away and reused by the time this closure runs
                // the code we just wrote to init the cellImageView works just fine
                // call that using reload

                if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                }
            }
        }];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:10];
    nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Title"];
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Make the cell transparent
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new];

    // Resize the cell
    [cell sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

Edit -- don't bother with this for now, but -- if you really do have the opportunity to prepare the view before its shown (like maybe this view controller is in a tab bar container and not the default tab). You could use the table view helper methods to do a pre-fetch of the visible rows...

```
- (void)prepareToBeShown {
    NSArray indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];    
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (![self.shownIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {

        [self.shownIndexes addObject:indexPath];
        UIView *weeeeCell = [cell contentView];

        weeeeCell.layer.transform = self.initialTransform;
        weeeeCell.layer.opacity = 0.8;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:0 animations:^{
            weeeeCell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
            weeeeCell.layer.opacity = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I get your point, but I don't completely understand the meaning and how to implement your code. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Erik - see the edit.  Placed the code suggestion in the context.  Just paste the instance variable and the improved cellForRowAtIndexPath into your view controller.

Comment: Great answer - thorough, succinct explanation

Comment: @danh getting a few errors now with that code. I understand the errors but I don't understand why they would appear there

Comment: @danh we declare a PFFile inside the if-statement which I had no problems doing before, but now - with the code in your answer, it tells me these 2 errors: “Use of undeclared identifier ‘imageFile’” (Which we declare?? Don't understand why it says that) and “Unexpected interface name ‘PFFile’, expected expression”

Comment: @Erik - see the line just before?  Its incomplete because I left a comment there for you to add a placeholder image.  Comment out that whole line above, or assign a nil placeholder image, or assign a real one [UIImage imageNamed:@"some-placeholder.png"];

Comment: @danh ohhh, sorry. I didn't notice the incomplete line. Filled it now and going to test :)

Comment: @danh it compiles and runs, but the UI is totally messy. the list flashes and jumps and lags. Looks weird. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Erik - I use this pattern all the time with good results.  I just reread your cell code, and it looks wrong (I just copied it in without reading).  Can you comment out the code under "//make the cell transparent", which is certainly wrong, and "// resize the cell".

Comment: @danh I think I might have found the culprit of the weird behaviour. Look at my updated question - I forgot to mention that I'm using that code for a custom row animation which I think is interfering with the if-statement I also added in my question. If I comment out the withRowAnimation it works, but it's still somewhat laggy while loading rows from server.

Comment: @danh I think the 2 blocks of code are fighting over how the row should be presented. I tried to comment out the row with "withAnimation" and then the weird behaviour disappears - but it's still somewhat laggy. Also it doesn't download the images - it just displays the placeholder image..

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a PFImageView instead of a UIImageView?

All you have to do it set it's file and tell it to load in the background. I've never had any lag when using them in my tableviews.

Comment: Isn't that what my code is doing? I'm using the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock method so if I use the PFImageView I should be good?

Comment: You may also be able to try fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock instead.

Comment: Where? Could you please elaborate:)

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of pfobject's call there. I'm just wondering if if it is fetching the data for images it already has downloaded again.

Comment: Yeah, it downloads the images whenever the cells are shown, for instance when the user scrolls up and down. I could create an array of images to solve this, but it has to download the images atleast once, so there will be some lag during the first scroll :/

Comment: what about using the isDataAvailable property and only fetch if there is no data available? I will try to test this out and see

Comment: I've just tested out a tableview with your type of image loading and it works fine. The scrolling isn't laggy at all. Obvoiusly image loads are size dependent but not slow scrolling. Something else may be the issue